# Find 1s in almost all 0 array using comparisons only

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, python, comparison, dynamic-algorithms

So, we are given a 100 long array, with 97 0s and 3 1s of which we do not know the locations. We must find them using only a compare function, which I managed to write (in Python):

```
def compare(i, j):
    comparisons.append((i, j))
    if data[i] == data[j]:
        return 0 
    else:
        return 1 if data[i] > data[j] else -1
```

Using this function, we must find all three 1s with using at most 73 comparisons. We must output the compared pairs as a tuple as well as the coordinates of the three 1s.

Now, I tried writing a code with the following logic:
[image: simple logic using 3 comparisons for 4 elements]

And I thought that maybe because two 1s will use 2 instead of 3 comparisons, it might come down do 73. This was not only long to code (I am studying mathematics, not CS), but I wrote to my prof, and he said this wouldn't work, and that I should try dynamic programming. I'm a bit lost, as I've never solved a coding program that is this limiting, so I have an other idea, which is to do a first parse of the array, going in pairs, so comparing (data[0], data[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ukm7.png)),(data[2], data[3]),.... This way, no matter how the 1s are placed, I ought to find at least one of them. I would also store all of the results of these comparisons, and then cross-check them with a set of new comparisons, namely (data[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ukm7.png),data[2]),(data[5],data[6]),...

Any help is appreciated, specific code would be most useful, so I can understand how such a method would work.

Edit:
I almost have it now thanks to @orlp, but I don't see why I still get 75 comparisons:

```
comparisons = []

def compare(i, j):
 comparisons.append((i, j))
 if data[i] == data[j]:
   return 0 
 else:
   return 1 if data[i] > data[j] else -1

def find_ones(data):
 found_ones = []

 for i in range(0, len(data), 2):
   if compare(i, i + 1) != 0:
     found_ones.append(i if data[i] == 1 else i + 1)
     if len(found_ones) == 3:
       return comparisons, found_ones[0], found_ones[1], found_ones[2]

 remaining_pairs = [i for i in range(0, len(data), 2) if i not in found_ones]
 for i in range(0, len(remaining_pairs) - 1, 2):
   if compare(remaining_pairs[i], remaining_pairs[i + 1]) != 0: 
     found_ones.extend([remaining_pairs[i], remaining_pairs[i + 1]])
     break

 if len(found_ones) == 1:
   found_ones.extend(remaining_pairs[-2:])

 return comparisons, found_ones[0], found_ones[1], found_ones[2]


def get_input_data():
 position_1 = int(input("Enter position of first '1' (0-99): "))
 position_2 = int(input("Enter position of second '1' (0-99): "))
 position_3 = int(input("Enter position of third '1' (0-99): "))

 data = [0] * 100
 data[position_1] = data[position_2] = data[position_3] = 1
 return data


data = get_input_data()
comparisons, a, b, c = find_ones(data.copy()) 

print("Comparisons:")
for pair in comparisons:
 print(pair)

print("\nPositions of '1's:")
print(a, b, c)

print("\nNumber of comparisons:", len(comparisons))
```

I included the optimizations at the end, didn't I? Don't do the last comparison, if only one 1 has been found the first time around, and the second time don't do the last comparison, because by then we know them to be 1s.

Edit 2:
I fixed, some of the issues in the first half, but I just do not see why it isn't down to 73 steps. Also now, it is returning false values. What am I doing wrong?

```
comparisons = []
    
def compare(i, j):
    comparisons.append((i, j))
    if data[i] == data[j]:
        return 0 
    else:
        return 1 if data[i] > data[j] else -1

def find_ones(data):
    found_ones = []

    # Step 1: Initial pairing and comparisons
    for i in range(0, len(data)-2, 2):
        if compare(i, i + 1) != 0:  # One of them is a '1'
            found_ones.append(i if data[i] == 1 else i + 1)
            if len(found_ones) == 3:  # Found all three '1's
                return comparisons, found_ones[0], found_ones[1], found_ones[2]

            
            
      # Check if we need to compare the final pair
    if len(found_ones) == 2:
        result = compare(len(data) - 2, len(data) - 1)
        if result == 1:   # '1' is at index len(data) - 2
          found_ones.append(len(data) - 2)
        elif result == -1:  # '1' is at index len(data) - 1
          found_ones.append(len(data) - 1)
        
    if len(found_ones) == 3:  # Found all three '1's
                return comparisons, found_ones[0], found_ones[1], found_ones[2]

            
    # Step 2: Find the pair with the remaining two '1's
    remaining_pairs = [i for i in range(0, len(data), 2) if i not in found_ones]
    for i in range(0, len(remaining_pairs) - 1, 2):
        if compare(remaining_pairs[i], remaining_pairs[i + 1]) != 0:  # Found the (1, 1) pair
            found_ones.extend([remaining_pairs[i], remaining_pairs[i + 1]])
            break

    # Step 3: If necessary, deduce the last pair
    if len(found_ones) == 1:
        found_ones.extend(remaining_pairs[-2:])  # The remaining pair must be (1, 1)

    return comparisons, found_ones[0], found_ones[1], found_ones[2]


# Example usage
def get_input_data():
    # Replace this with your preferred input method (e.g., user input)
    position_1 = int(input("Enter position of first '1' (0-99): "))
    position_2 = int(input("Enter position of second '1' (0-99): "))
    position_3 = int(input("Enter position of third '1' (0-99): "))

    data = [0] * 100
    data[position_1] = data[position_2] = data[position_3] = 1
    return data


data = get_input_data()
comparisons, a, b, c = find_ones(data.copy())  # Use copy to avoid modifying original 

print("Comparisons:")
for pair in comparisons:
    print(pair)

print("\nPositions of '1's:")
print(a, b, c)

print("\nNumber of comparisons:", len(comparisons))
```

Edit 3:

```
comparisons = []
   
def compare(i, j):
  comparisons.append((i, j))
  if data[i] == data[j]:
    return 0 
  else:
    return 1 if data[i] > data[j] else -1

def find_ones(data):
  found_ones = []
  excluded_indices = set()  # Track indices already found

  # Step 1: Initial pairing and comparisons
  for i in range(0, len(data) - 2, 2): 
    result = compare(i, i + 1)
    if result == 1:  
     found_ones.append(i)
     excluded_indices.update({i, i + 1})  # Update excluded indices
    elif result == -1: 
     found_ones.append(i + 1)
     excluded_indices.update({i, i - 1})  # Update excluded indices

    if len(found_ones) == 3: 
        return comparisons, found_ones[0], found_ones[1], found_ones[2]
   
   # Check if we need to compare the final pair
  if len(found_ones) == 2 and (len(data) - 2) not in excluded_indices and (len(data) - 1) not in excluded_indices: 
    result = compare(len(data) - 2, len(data) - 1)
    if result == 1:  
     found_ones.append(len(data) - 2)
     excluded_indices.update({len(data) - 2, len(data) - 1})  # Update excluded indices
    elif result == -1: 
     found_ones.append(len(data) - 1)
     excluded_indices.update({len(data) - 2, len(data) - 1})  # Update excluded indices

  if len(found_ones) == 3:
        return comparisons, found_ones[0], found_ones[1], found_ones[2]
       
  # Step 2: Find the pair with the remaining two '1's
  remaining_pairs = [i for i in range(0, len(data), 2) if i not in excluded_indices] 
  for i in range(0, len(remaining_pairs) - 1, 2):
    if compare(remaining_pairs[i], remaining_pairs[i + 1]) != 0:
      found_ones.extend([remaining_pairs[i], remaining_pairs[i + 1]])
      break

  # Step 3: If necessary, deduce the last pair
  if len(found_ones) == 1:
    found_ones.extend(remaining_pairs[-2:])

  return comparisons, found_ones[0], found_ones[1], found_ones[2]

# Example usage
def get_input_data():
    position_1 = int(input("Enter position of first '1' (0-99): "))
    position_2 = int(input("Enter position of second '1' (0-99): "))
    position_3 = int(input("Enter position of third '1' (0-99): "))

    data = [0] * 100
    data[position_1] = data[position_2] = data[position_3] = 1
    return data


data = get_input_data()
comparisons, a, b, c = find_ones(data) 
print("Comparisons:")
for pair in comparisons:
    print(pair)

print("\nPositions of '1's:")
print(a, b, c)

print("\nNumber of comparisons:", len(comparisons))
```

Edit 4:
Okay, I believe I fixed the wrong excluding of the indexes, I now see how in both cases it must be i and i + 1. I still don't see how the logic in step 3 is wrong, but I did try to fix it in step 2. If we are in step 2 we still have an even number of elements, all of which hae previously been compared in pairs. Let's say we are here: (0,0)(1,1), where the parentheses mark the compared pairs from the first parse. The i-th element is the first zero of a pair (or the first 1 of a pair), so we compare it with the element that is 2 away from it, meaning the first element of the other pair. In this case we get remaining_pairs(i)<remaining_pairs(i+2), so we add i+2 and i+3 as being 1s. If it was the other way around, then we add i and i+1. It is still slightly off though, what is wrong?

```
comparisons = []

def compare(i, j):
  comparisons.append((i, j))
  if data[i] == data[j]:
    return 0 
  else:
    return 1 if data[i] > data[j] else -1

def find_ones(data):
  found_ones = []
  excluded_indices = set()  # Track indices already found

  # Step 1: Initial pairing and comparisons
  for i in range(0, len(data) - 2, 2): 
    result = compare(i, i + 1)
    if result == 1:  
     found_ones.append(i)
     excluded_indices.update({i, i + 1})  # Update excluded indices
    elif result == -1: 
     found_ones.append(i + 1)
     excluded_indices.update({i, i + 1})  # Update excluded indices

    if len(found_ones) == 3: 
        return comparisons, found_ones[0], found_ones[1], found_ones[2]

   # Check if we need to compare the final pair
  if len(found_ones) == 2 and (len(data) - 2) not in excluded_indices and (len(data) - 1) not in excluded_indices: 
    result = compare(len(data) - 2, len(data) - 1)
    if result == 1:  
     found_ones.append(len(data) - 2)
     excluded_indices.update({len(data) - 2, len(data) - 1})  # Update excluded indices
    elif result == -1: 
     found_ones.append(len(data) - 1)
     excluded_indices.update({len(data) - 2, len(data) - 1})  # Update excluded indices

  if len(found_ones) == 3:
        return comparisons, found_ones[0], found_ones[1], found_ones[2]

  # Step 2: Find the pair with the remaining two '1's
  remaining_pairs = [i for i in range(0, len(data), 2) if i not in excluded_indices] 
  for i in range(0, len(remaining_pairs) - 1, 2):
    result=compare(remaining_pairs[i], remaining_pairs[i + 2])
    if result == 1:
      found_ones.extend([remaining_pairs[i], remaining_pairs[i + 1]])
      break
    elif result == -1:
      found_ones.extend([remaining_pairs[i+2], remaining_pairs[i + 3]])
      break
    
  # Step 3: If necessary, deduce the last pair
  if len(found_ones) == 1:
    found_ones.extend(remaining_pairs[-2:])

  return comparisons, found_ones[0], found_ones[1], found_ones[2]

def get_input_data():
    position_1 = int(input("Enter position of first '1' (0-99): "))
    position_2 = int(input("Enter position of second '1' (0-99): "))
    position_3 = int(input("Enter position of third '1' (0-99): "))

    data = [0] * 100
    data[position_1] = data[position_2] = data[position_3] = 1
    return data


data = get_input_data()
comparisons, a, b, c = find_ones(data) 
print("Comparisons:")
for pair in comparisons:
    print(pair)

print("\nPositions of '1's:")
print(a, b, c)

print("\nNumber of comparisons:", len(comparisons))
```

Edit 5:
Do I have it?

````
comparisons = []

def compare(i, j):
  comparisons.append((i, j))
  if data[i] == data[j]:
    return 0 
  else:
    return 1 if data[i] > data[j] else -1

def find_ones(data):
  found_ones = []
  excluded_indices = set()  # Track indices already found

  # Step 1: Initial pairing and comparisons
  for i in range(0, len(data) - 2, 2): 
    result = compare(i, i + 1)
    if result == 1:  
     found_ones.append(i)
     excluded_indices.update({i, i + 1})  # Update excluded indices
    elif result == -1: 
     found_ones.append(i + 1)
     excluded_indices.update({i, i + 1})  # Update excluded indices

    if len(found_ones) == 3: 
        return comparisons, found_ones[0], found_ones[1], found_ones[2]

   # Check if we need to compare the final pair
  if len(found_ones) == 2 and (len(data) - 2) not in excluded_indices and (len(data) - 1) not in excluded_indices: 
    result = compare(len(data) - 2, len(data) - 1)
    if result == 1:  
     found_ones.append(len(data) - 2)
     excluded_indices.update({len(data) - 2, len(data) - 1})  # Update excluded indices
    elif result == -1: 
     found_ones.append(len(data) - 1)
     excluded_indices.update({len(data) - 2, len(data) - 1})  # Update excluded indices

  if len(found_ones) == 3:
        return comparisons, found_ones[0], found_ones[1], found_ones[2]

  # Step 2: Find the pair with the remaining two '1's
  remaining_pairs = [i for i in range(0, len(data)) if i not in excluded_indices] 
  for i in range(0, len(remaining_pairs) - 2, 4):
    result=compare(remaining_pairs[i], remaining_pairs[i + 2])
    if result == 1:
      found_ones.extend([remaining_pairs[i], remaining_pairs[i + 1]])
      break
    elif result == -1:
      found_ones.extend([remaining_pairs[i+2], remaining_pairs[i + 3]])
      break
    
  # Step 3: If necessary, deduce the last pair
  if len(found_ones) == 1:
    found_ones.extend(remaining_pairs[-2:])

  return comparisons, found_ones[0], found_ones[1], found_ones[2]

def get_input_data():
    position_1 = int(input("Enter position of first '1' (0-99): "))
    position_2 = int(input("Enter position of second '1' (0-99): "))
    position_3 = int(input("Enter position of third '1' (0-99): "))

    data = [0] * 100
    data[position_1] = data[position_2] = data[position_3] = 1
    return data


data = get_input_data()
comparisons, a, b, c = find_ones(data) 
print("Comparisons:")
for pair in comparisons:
    print(pair)

print("\nPositions of '1's:")
print(a, b, c)

print("\nNumber of comparisons:", len(comparisons))
```
````

Comment: Just FYI, on real CPUs memory access (even when hot in cache) has a cost, too, and a simple linear scan will be faster than shenanigans like this.  Especially when the things we're comparing are small integers that fit in 4 or preferably 1 byte.  On x86-64, you'd use SSE2 or AVX2 to check 16 or 32 bytes at once and get a bitmap of the non-zero elements (`pcmpeqb` / `pmovmskb`), then loop over the set bits if any and use `tzcnt` to find their positions.  (`mask &= mask-1` to clear the lowest set bit, x86 `blsr`).  So this is a fun exercise but not practically relevant for this specific problem.

Comment: In more abstract terms, CS often assumes an O(1) cost to access one element of memory, but in the real world a better approximation is O(log MemUsed) due to cache effects.

Comment: It seems to be possible to do this in 70 comparisons, worst case.  (I implemented an algorithm to _compute_ an optimal algorithm, using, in some sense, dynamic programming.)  If I get a chance I'll post the code somewhere (it's large).  [maybe interesting to @orlp]

Comment: @NealYoung I'd love to see the code

Comment: The code is currently here: https://github.com/nealeyoung/find_three_ones .

Comment: @NealYoung that is really impressive, but unfortunately much of what you wrote is completely beyond me. I hope to one day be able to conjure up that sort of code, but until then do you see any easier routes to the solution? Like can my existing code be in any way modified to obtain the solution. Am I missing something simple, or do I have to figure out the sort of optimal algorithm you found?

Comment: I added some explanation in the README there, but it probably will take some work (inspecting the computed algorithm carefully) to get some ideas about what it might be doing.  In this spirit, one thing you could do is use the code as a black box to "solve" (compute optimal algorithms for) smaller instances of the problem (e.g. 3 ones and 10 zeros).   I did a little bit of this, and found out some suggestive things, but nothing conclusive.

Comment: @NealYoung I understand the basic intuition behind it, especially up until the equivalence relation logic, but there is no way I could ever actually code this. That's why I'm looking for a simpler algorithmic approach, wherein I find the algorithm, but I'm really stuck. Those 6 inputs (out of 161700 aaaaa) seem to be defeating me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151939/discussion-between-neal-young-and-user555076).

Answer (score 13):

Start by splitting the 100 elements in 50 pairs of two, and use a comparison on each pair. If a comparison returns -1 or 1, then you've found one of the elements which is 1 (and the other one must be a 0).

Now there are two cases after these 50 comparisons: either we've found all three 1's, or we've found one 1, because the remaining two were part of the same pair. In the latter case we must find the pair which contains the last two 1's.

In this case there will be 49 pairs left (we can exclude the (0, 1) pair we identified earlier) one of which is the (1, 1) pair. We can find it by pairing the pairs, and doing one comparison each (for a total of 24 comparisons, leaving one pair out). This will identify which pair is the one with (1, 1), or if not, we know it must be the last pair.

This gives a total of 74 comparions. In fact, we could have saved one more comparison in the first step by stopping after 49 comparisons. If we have found two 1's in those first 49 comparisons we do one more to find the last 1 and we are done, and if we've found only one 1 it's useless to perform the comparison on the last pair, as it could only be (0, 0) or (1, 1), giving us no information.

Comment: I think I almost figured it out, check my edit please

Comment: An interesting question would be: What is the average number of comparisons if you pick the pairs at random?

Comment: _"This gives a total of 74 comparions. In fact, we could have saved one more comparison in the first step by stopping after 49 comparisons. If we have found two 1's in those first 49 comparisons we do one more to find the last 1 and we are done, and if we've found only one 1 it's useless to perform the comparison on the last pair, as it could only be (0, 0) or (1, 1), giving us no information."_  Wait, what about the case where you find zero ones in the first 49 comparisons?  Then you know the missing pair is a zero and a one, but you don't know which is which...

Comment: @NealYoung The OP specified that we know there are 3 ones in the input. So it's not possible that we find zero ones in the first 49 comparisons.

Comment: Can't it be that the 49 pairs that your algorithm first compares consist of 48 (0,0)'s and a single (1, 1), and the 50th pair (that your algorithm doesn't compare) is (0, 1)?  In that case, your algorithm will not find any ones in the first 49 comparisons.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @NealYoung Ah, you are right that is a missing case. I don't know how to achieve 73 comparisons in those circumstances. Pairing the pairs gives 49+24 = 73 comparisons to identify the (1, 1) pair, but that leaves two possibilities for the last pair, (0, 1) and (1, 0).

Comment: @NealYoung Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @orlp do you think it is possible to solve those problematic inputs. I found them to be :
[92, 93, 98]
[92, 93, 99]
[94, 95, 98]
[94, 95, 99]
[96, 97, 98]
[96, 97, 99]

Answer (score 2):

Your current code has the following issues:

> `for i in range(0, len(data), 2):`

This is where you need to put the optimization to (conditionally) avoid comparing the final pair. You have two options for how to do that optimization:

- Subtract 2 from the endpoint of the range, and then check after the loop for whether comparing the final pair is necessary.
- Or check inside the loop whether the current pair is the final pair and whether comparing the final pair is necessary. If it's the final pair and comparing it is not needed, then skip the `compare` call.

Choose one or the other of those solutions, not both.

> `found_ones.append(i if data[i] == 1 else i + 1)`

Checking the value of `data[i]` in this line breaks the problem requirement of only checking data values in the `compare` function. You need to instead check whether the returned result from `compare` is 1 or -1 to determine which element in the pair is the 1. In doing this, you will also need to avoid making duplicate `compare` calls. One way to avoid the duplicate call is to use a `match` statement. Another is to save the result value to a variable so you can check that variable for the value multiple times without re-invoking the function call.

> `remaining_pairs = [i for i in range(0, len(data), 2) if i not in found_ones]`

This does not reliably filter out the pair that you found a 1 in. It filters the indexes of the first element in each pair, and fails to filter out the found pair if the found 1 is the second element in its pair.

> `if compare(remaining_pairs[i], remaining_pairs[i + 1]) != 0:`

This neglects to check which of the two pairs is a pair of 1s and which is a pair of 0s. Do this by checking whether the return value is 1 or -1, and again make sure to avoid duplicate `compare` calls as I noted earlier.

> `found_ones.extend([remaining_pairs[i], remaining_pairs[i + 1]])`

This adds the first element of each of the pairs. It should instead be adding **both** elements of **one** of the pairs. Make sure to use the result of the `compare` call to determine which pair to add.

> `found_ones.extend(remaining_pairs[-2:])`

Same problem as the previous one. This adds the first element of each of the last two pairs. It should instead be adding both elements of the last pair.

Edit responding to your comment and "Edit 2":

> I tried to implement some of your advice, and I do not see how I am wrong. I corrected the inappropriate use of something other than my compare function, but I can't get the logic right with the optimizations.

You fixed the inappropriate check of `data[i]` in your new post-loop check of the final pair, but it's still there in the first loop itself.

Now, going through your code responses to the issues in order:

1. Conditional `compare` of the final pair for the first loop: You solved this correctly.
2. Checking the return value of `compare` instead of directly checking `data[i]`: You only partially finished this. You got it right for the final pair, but you need to also apply the same fix inside the first loop.
3. Fixing the buggy filtering of `remaining_pairs`: You missed this completely, and it will sometimes cause incorrect results until you fix it. As an example to show the issue, consider the data set `[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, ..., 1, 1]`. After the first loop, `found_ones` will be `[3]`. The filter you use to fill `remaining_pairs` will check if 2 is in `found_ones`, find it is not, and will include 2 in the resulting value of `remaining_pairs`. This is a bug because the 2 index is the other element of the pair that the 1 was found in and should therefore be excluded from `remaining_pairs`.
4. Checking the return value of `compare` to find which pair has the remaining two 1s: You missed this completely. Some inputs will get wrong results until this is fixed.
5. Fixing which index values to add after finding the last two 1s in the second loop: You missed this completely. Some inputs will get wrong results until this is fixed. For example, consider the data set `[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1]`. The current code will report that it found 1s at positions 0 and 2 (and 99 but that's irrelevant to this issue), but the correct result is that those first two 1s are at positions 2 and 3.
6. Fixing which index values to add after finding that the last two 1s are the last pair: You missed this completely. Inputs where the last two data values are 1s will get wrong results until this is fixed.

Responding to "Edit 3":

1. `excluded_indices` is a good addition, but one of the `update` calls on it is wrong. The correct indices to exclude when you find a 1 in the first loop are always `{i, i + 1}`, because that is the pair that you compared regardless of which part of the pair is the 1.
2. This one technically isn't *wrong*, as in it won't cause your code to produce incorrect results, but checking `excluded_indices` in the condition for comparing the final pair is pointless. The indices of the final pair cannot possibly be in `excluded_indices` at that point in the code, because the final pair hasn't been checked yet.
3. You still haven't fixed issues 4, 5, and 6 from my previous edit. Those are for the sections of code that you labeled as step 2 and step 3.

Comment: I tried to implement some of your advice, and I do not see how I am wrong. I corrected the inappropriate use of something other than my compare function, but I can't get the logic right with the optimizations. I understand that if before the last comparison in the first parsewe have found 2 1s, only then do we have to make that last comparison. On the other hand, if we only one 1 before the last comparison of the second parse, the last two must both be 1s. Now I even get false results. I don't understand what I am doing wrong

Comment: I believe i got the first parse right, but the second i just cant fix

Comment: @user555076 I added a response to your new code.

Comment: Okay, wow now i think i am really close. I believe now therew is only an indexing error somewhere, but i just dont see where. It is definitely in step 2 or 3. It does 73 comparisons, but saves the wrong indices. I don't know what is misindexed

Comment: @user555076 New edit. You're getting close.

Comment: I tried to correct the mistakes you mentioned, but it is still a bit off, I think I should be really close! Please check the new edit, thank you for helping in advance!

Comment: @user555076 Consider what exactly the contents of `remaining_pairs` is, and how the meaning of those contents is fundamentally different from the contents of `data`. Then consider what that implies about which value you should be adjusting at each point where you add a number. What can you figure out from that, and if you can't solve it yet then at what point in trying to answer this question are you stuck? I'll keep giving you hints, but there's an important lesson about certain kinds of details to learn from this, and you'll learn it much better if the final realization is your own.

Comment: I believe my current code is correct. I have to jump 4 every time because I am comparing adjacent pairs. Is there still something wrong with the code? It is functioning properly, I don’t see anything i missed

Comment: Also I had a wrong idea about what remaining_pairs looked like, but it should be fine now

Comment: @user555076 Ah, I missed that in edit 5 you removed the step parameter from the `range` call for making `remaining_pairs`. That change makes the name of the variable inaccurate and misleading, and you should have changed the name to something like `remaining_indices` when you changed its definition. Accuracy of names is important for readability of your code. With that said, that change does fix the issues I was talking about.

Comment: @user555076 However, some quick testing revealed another bug. Running your code from edit 5 and giving it the input positions 2, 3, and 99 causes it to throw an error. In step 1, the final pair needs to be checked if either 2 **or 0** 1s were found by the first loop.

Comment: Wow, how did you spot that, I would never have thought of that. Why does it throw an error? This time around, it's not the code, but the logic I don't understand.

Comment: @user555076 When the first loop doesn't find anything (because the first two 1s are together in the same pair and the third 1 is beyond its scope in the final pair), it skips checking the final pair, so it doesn't find the third 1. Step 2 then finds the first two 1s, but the last 1 remains not found. It then tries to return 3 values from `found_ones`, but there are only 2 values there. The error is an `IndexError` for attempting to access `found_ones[2]` in the last return statement, with `found_ones` containing only `[2,3]`.

Comment: Ooh, i see, so it is the 99 that it doesn't find. I thought it was the (2,3) it didn’t find, but this makes sense. It didn’t know what to do, because after the first loop it ought to have already found at least one 1, but in that case it missed everything. And if we didn’t find anything in the first loop before the last comparison, there must be exactly one 1 in that pair, otherwise we would’ve found a 1 before. Thank you for all your help, it has truly been invaluable, I’ve learnt much, you’ve been a great teacher!

Comment: I just found it does 74 comparisons for 98, 92, 93. Do you have any idea why? It must have to do with 98, 99 being out, but I don't see what's wrong

Comment: It must have to do with 98, 99 being out, but I don't see what's wrong. I think it is that the last comparison is forced in the first parse, but I don't know how it can be cut.

Comment: ```
Failed for input with 1s at [92, 93, 98], found [92, 93, 98] with 74 comparisons.
Failed for input with 1s at [92, 93, 99], found [92, 93, 99] with 74 comparisons.
Failed for input with 1s at [94, 95, 98], found [94, 95, 98] with 74 comparisons.
Failed for input with 1s at [94, 95, 99], found [94, 95, 99] with 74 comparisons.
Failed for input with 1s at [96, 97, 98], found [96, 97, 98] with 74 comparisons.
Failed for input with 1s at [96, 97, 99], found [96, 97, 99] with 74 comparisons.
```

Comment: @user555076 I found an avenue to explore, but it's tricky. On the final pair, just comparing the 2 numbers with each other has only 2 possible outcomes, even though `compare` has 3 return values. Comparing part of the final pair to a different pair instead can gain more information. For example, if you compare element 98 to another pair and find that element 98 is less than the pair, then that pins down all of the 1s immediately - they have to be element 99 and whichever pair you compared to. I haven't figured out how to leverage this to guarantee 73 or fewer total comparisons, though.

Comment: In the problematic inputs we haven't yet found any 1s by the time we reached the final pair. Comparing it to something else would involve a random guess then, no? I was thinking maybe when we found 0 1s before comparing the final pair, we don't compare them. And maybe there is some logic to finish the second parse more efficiently?